# MQL4 array creating variables

Tags: arrays, mql4

I'm trying to make this function create X number of variables using an array. I know that this is technically wrong because I need a constant as my array's value (currently 'x'), but excluding that, what am I missing? Looked at so many code samples and can't figure it out, but I know it's got to be simple...

```
void variables()
{
   int i;
   int bars = 10;
   int x = 1;

   for (i = 1; i <= bars+1; i++)
      {
         int variables[bars] = { x };
         x++;

         if (i >= bars+1)
            {
               break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void variables()
{
  int bars = 10;
  if(bars >= Bars) bars = Bars - 1;

  // to be able to set array size based on variable,
  //                   make a dynamically sized array

  double highvalues[];
  ArrayResize(highvalues, bars);


  for (int i = 0 /*Note: Array index is zero-based, 0 is first*/; i <= bars; i++)
  {
     highvalues[i] = iHigh(NULL, 0, i);
     // or
     highvalues[i] = High[i];

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what do you want to achieve.

If you want to fill an array with a value *ArrayFill()* fill help you.

Comment: In MQL4 I want to use the iHigh, iLow, iClose functions for ~500 bars.  To save time (and learn coding better), I wanted to simplify it so that the variable i (the 'shift' or bar number to the left) is handled by the for statement, so I don't have to manually type in 1,500 entries (3 functions listed above * 500 bars).  The for statement listed in my code above is only to generate the variables for the other functions. Does that clarify a bit better?